# Why are there multiple ways of initializing variables in c++?

Tags: c++

Why are there multiple ways of initializing variables in c++ instead of just one?
From my knowledge you can do these:

```
int x = 0;
int y (2);
int c {3};
```

Thanks!

Comment: Past mistakes + backwards compatibility = redundancy. This is very opinion based and broad.

Comment: @nwp, nah sure? I mean the answer should probably just be something like: "it is simply for readability" or "this one ... is quite different because it takes blablabl" :)

Answer (score -2):

Oh, it is because , all of datatypes are an object.
They all have blind initializers, that is same as the default-constructor(initializer) of the classes.